# Selenium webdriver auto install chrome app

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-app

I want to run chrome from selenium with particular **app** installed in it. I am aware that we can load extensions in the chrome driver as explained [here](https://www.google.com.hk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=strict&q=selenium%20start%20chrome%20browser%20with%20extension%20installed%20load%20app). I have tried to use the same code for unpacked app however it gives an error:

```
failed to load extension manifest file is missing or unreadable
```